# Variable isn't being multiplied in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, class, echo

`$newtotal` isn't being multiplied in php.

I want the `$newtotal` to be echoed but it's only echoing the number 0. I want to be able to get the value of the span class `total-cart` and have it multiplied in php. It's not letting due to the javascript. I have added all the javascript info underneath the php.

**PHP**

```
<span class= "total-cart"></span>
<?php 
 echo '<span class="total-cart"></span>'; 
 echo $total-cart;
 $newtotal= $total-cart*3;    
 echo $newtotal;
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
// Shopping Cart API
var shoppingCart = (function() {
// Private methods and propeties
cart = [];

// Constructor
function Item(name, price, count) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.count = count;
}

// Save cart
function saveCart() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', 
JSON.stringify(cart));
}

// Load cart
function loadCart() {
cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
}
if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
  loadCart();
}

// Public methods and propeties
var obj = {};

// Add to cart
obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price, count) {
for(var item in cart) {
  if(cart[item].name === name) {
    cart[item].count ++;
    saveCart();
    return;
  }
}
var item = new Item(name, price, count);
cart.push(item);
saveCart();
}
// Set count from item
obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
for(var i in cart) {
  if (cart[i].name === name) {
    cart[i].count = count;
    break;
  }
}
};
// Remove item from cart
obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
  for(var item in cart) {
    if(cart[item].name === name) {
      cart[item].count --;
      if(cart[item].count === 0) {
        cart.splice(item, 1);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  saveCart();
}

// Remove all items from cart
obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
for(var item in cart) {
  if(cart[item].name === name) {
    cart.splice(item, 1);
    break;
  }
  }
saveCart();
}

// Clear cart
obj.clearCart = function() {
cart = [];
saveCart();
}

// Count cart 
obj.totalCount = function() {
var totalCount = 0;
for(var item in cart) {
  totalCount += cart[item].count;
}
return totalCount;
}

// Total cart
obj.totalCart = function() {
var totalCart = 0;
for(var item in cart) {
  totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
}
return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
}

// List cart
obj.listCart = function() {
var cartCopy = [];
for(i in cart) {
  item = cart[i];
  itemCopy = {};
  for(p in item) {
    itemCopy[p] = item[p];

  }
  itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * 
item.count).toFixed(2);
  cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
}
return cartCopy;
}

// cart : Array
// Item : Object/Class
// addItemToCart : Function
// removeItemFromCart : Function
// removeItemFromCartAll : Function
// clearCart : Function
// countCart : Function
// totalCart : Function
// listCart : Function
// saveCart : Function
// loadCart : Function
return obj;
})();

// Triggers / Events
// Add item
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var name = $(this).data('name');
var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
displayCart();
});

// Clear items
$('.clear-cart').click(function() {
shoppingCart.clearCart();
displayCart();
});

function displayCart() {
var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
var output = "";
for(var i in cartArray) {
output += "<tr>"
  + "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" 
  + "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>"
  + "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus- 
item input-group-addon btn btn-primary' data-name=" + 
cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>"
  + "<input type='number' class='item-count form- 
control' data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" 
+ cartArray[i].count + "'>"
  + "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input- 
group-addon' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>"
  + "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">X</button></td>"
  + " = " 
  + "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" 
  +  "</tr>";
}
$('.show-cart').html(output);
$('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
$('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}

// Delete item button
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", 
function(event) {
var name = $(this).data('name')
shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
displayCart();
})


// -1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
var name = $(this).data('name')
shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
displayCart();
})
// +1
$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
 var name = $(this).data('name')
shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
displayCart();
})

// Item count input
$('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
var name = $(this).data('name');
var count = Number($(this).val());
shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
displayCart();
});

displayCart();
</script>
```

Comment: in php, you can't use dashes in variable names. So `$total-cart` is an invalid name.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to have PHP do the math AFTER javascript has been used to create the initial value you'll need to look into AJAX posts and how to handle them.  An example might be as follows:

**JS** (JQUERY for simplicity)

```
$.post('path/to/your/phpscript.php', {type: "multi", value: cartvalue}, function(returned) {
  console.log(returned);  //Do whatever you need to do with the value now.
});
```

**PHP AJAX Handle**

```
  $returnthis;
  switch($_POST['type']) {
    case "multi":
         //Do your multiplication here.  Your initial value is stored in $_POST['value'].
    //ie - $returnthis = $_POST['value'] * 3;
    break;
  }
  return $returnthis;
```

Comment: didn't work for me. Any code after the PHP AJAX Handle would stop working.

Comment: If you are placing them both in the same file thats not how that is meant to work.

JS is the file you are displaying the value in ultimately.

The Ajax file rests on the server and is called only to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

`cart` is not available in your PHP (PHP can't read JS variables).

What you can do is put `$newTotal` in a hidden field. Then use your JS to pull in the value of that hidden field and do your calculation and use JS to print it to the screen.

**PHP**

```
<span class= "total-cart"></span>
<?php 
 echo '<span class="total-cart"></span>'; 
 echo $total-cart;
 $newtotal= $total-cart*3;    
 echo '<input type="hidden" id="newTotal" value="'.$newtotal.'"/>';
 echo '<span id="output"></span>';
?>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementsById('output').innerText = parseInt(document.getElementsById('newTotal'), 10) - cart * 3;
```

Just noticed you use jQuery, you can also do it as follows

```
$('#output').text(parseInt($('#newTotal').value(), 10) - cart * 3);
```

**Note** *You will need to use parseInt to convert the value from `#newTotal` from a string to an Integer*